# Get current ip-address Xamarin.Forms ( Cross Platform)

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform, ip-address, xamarin.forms

How get current ip-address for Xamarin.Forms ( Cross Platform) ? WifiManager I can't use and can't WifiManager include?

Comment: You would have to write yourself a dependency service or use Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Services.Resolver and write a platform-dependent service for each platform, then use the platform-independent interface to call it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public string MyIp;

foreach (IPAddress adress in Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()))
{
    MyIp = "IP Adress: " + adress.ToString();
    SettingsTab.IP_Adress = MyIp;
    break;
}
```

Comment: This takes the `AddressFamily.InterNetwork` address.

Comment: What if you have 2 connections, i.e WiFi and Ethernet on UWP?  How do you know which one is the one being in use?  Breaking just on grabbing first one doesnt guarantee you are using the correct one

Answer (score 8):

Or try this:

```
var IpAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName()).FirstOrDefault();

if (IpAddress != null)
{
    return IpAddress.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to do this:

```
    public static string GetIPAddress()
    {
        var AllNetworkInterfaces = Collections.List(Java.Net.NetworkInterface.NetworkInterfaces);
        var IPAddres = "";
        foreach (var interfaces in AllNetworkInterfaces)
        {
            if (!(interfaces as Java.Net.NetworkInterface).Name.Contains("eth0")) continue;

            var AddressInterface = (interfaces as Java.Net.NetworkInterface).InterfaceAddresses;
            foreach (var AInterface in AddressInterface)
            {
                if(AInterface.Broadcast != null)
                    IPAddres = AInterface.Address.HostAddress;
            }
        }
            return IPAddres;
    }
```