# Xamarin Android - Webclient

Tags: c#, php, mysql, xamarin, webclient

I'm trying to build an app for android (school project (technology)), however, 
I'm keep getting an error and searching on the internet, gave no answer. So I'm hereby asking in here.

I got an MySQL 5.6 Server up and running, it works. PHP standalone and Xampp for file directory, and everything works fine in browser.  The error occurs on the the arrow sign and exception error is about access (I think). I can upload the PHP files if needed.
The first one is a button, the second is an event fired when download is complete.

```
private void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextView userName = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.editTextUsername);
        TextView userPass = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.editTextPassword);

        client = new WebClient();
        url = new Uri(@"http://127.0.0.1/memento/accountcheck.php");
        //url = new Uri(@"http://127.0.0.1/memento/phpinfo.php");

        /*
        NameValueCollection parameters = new NameValueCollection();

        parameters.Add("Username", userName.Text);
        parameters.Add("Password", userPass.Text);
        */

        client.DownloadDataCompleted += Client_DownloadDataCompleted;
        client.DownloadDataAsync(url);

    }

private void Client_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Result); // <------
    }
```

EDIT:

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException for exception details.
>   Exception Settings: C++ Exceptions, Common Language Runtime Exceptions, JavaScript Runtime Exceptions, Managed Debugging Assistants & Win32 Exceptions.

Each contain tons of check checkboxes except JavaScript. It contains one "0x80070005 Access is denied".

Comment: Can you post the error/exception and mark the line where it is thrown?

Comment: when it tells you "Check InnerException for exception details." that is exactly what you should do.  Also note that you're using the loopback address, this won't work because your server and your android app are running on different machines (even if you're using the Android emulator, it does not share the IP of the host).  You need to use the actual external IP or name of your server.

Comment: Jason, thanks a lot! It seems like using my local IP instead of localhost/127.0.0.1 it fixed the problem! I thought, it ran on the same unit and shared the same IP.

Comment: A more generic solution is to request the current IP address by resolving the local host using a DNS, like shown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904375/get-current-ip-address-xamarin-forms-cross-platform).